# Is it possible to extrude a shape (like a U.S. state) with D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to extrude a shape using D3, such as a U.S. state based upon an attribute value?

For example, in this graphic, the states are extruded based upon some attribute value, which could be something like population or income.

[image: Extruded shapes]

Comment: I've done something similar with d3 and three.js -- check it out on [github](https://github.com/ledbettj/us-map/tree/threejs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 doesn't offer support for 3D shapes. So in principle, the answer is yes as long as you're willing to code the 3D part yourself. You are however most likely much better off using a library that supports this explicitly (like [three.js](http://threejs.org/)), maybe in conjunction with D3.